# Non-English Text coming as shown in image attached in my android application

Tags: android, rendering

[image: Telegu text getting displayed as this in android application]

I'm fetching telegu(String) from the server and then, setting textview to the String received after fetch. Generally, It is displaying the right text but sometimes, text comes as shown in image.

Text coming from server is (కృష్ణ డిస్ట్రిక్ట్ గృహ సర్వే)

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Post how you are receiving the text from the server.

Comment: @EugeneH : I edited the question. Added the text I'm getting from server

Answer (score 0):

You must be using iso encoding, use utf-8 encoding

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding only. The major problem is: it is coming fine generally, but suddenly in between it shows me this and then, it disappears automatically and normal text comes up.